# Powershell Modify Emailaddresses in Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am trying add text before all the email address, instead of that it overwriting and creating one copy of email address of the last. Any ideas what is causing this?

```
$UD = Get-Mailbox -Identity $_identity
$SmtpAdd=$UD|select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses|Select SmtpAddress
foreach($address in $SmtpAdd)
    {
    $Changed="Disabled_"+$($address.SmtpAddress)
    Set-Mailbox $_identity -EmailAddresses $Chnged -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true

    }
```

expecting output: `Disabled_rave@in.com,Disabled_raj@in.com`

but it is giving: `Disabled_raj@in.com,raj@in.com.`

It is not adding `Disabled` in all the mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actual results indicate that $($address.SmtpAddress) is a string. In such case, you are combing two strings:

```
"a" + "b,c" and the results of this operation will be "ab,c"
```

So you need to split $($address.SmtpAddress) by **','** ,add "Disabled_" for each element, store all new email address inside array and then join those elements as string using ',':

```
[array]$Changed = $null
$($address.SmtpAddress) -split ',' | % {
    $Changed += "Disabled_"+ $_
    }
$Changed = $Changed -join ','
Set-Mailbox $_identity -EmailAddresses $Chnged -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true
```

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: Ok so please check what data type is $($address.SmtpAddress):
$($address.SmtpAddress).GetType()
$($address.SmtpAddress) | % { $_.GetType() }put This code inside loop

Comment: type is system.string,

Comment: You are doing something wrong, look at this: [array]$Changed = $null ; "b@b.com,c@c.com" -split ',' | % { $Changed += "Disabled_"+ $_ } ; $Changed = $Changed -join ',' ; $Changed - this will produce correct results

Comment: Finally i got my solution, i misunderstand the concept of array. Thanks for your support brother

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that my posts helped you.